# Language Model for PocketSphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx, language-model

I've been working with PocketSphinx to make a speech recognizer for natural language. I don't want to use a grammar but rather a language model.
Is it possible that I can't find anything already-done online?
Everybody is linking [this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/) but it just contains the acoustic model, I'm looking for the .dmp or ARPA file with the statistical language model.
I could make it by myself but it's such a deal of time and I can't believe there is nothing to download for the english language.

Comment: You will get Language Model and Dict bundled with Acoustic Model.

Comment: Really? Cause I need a .dmp or bin or ARPA file. And I don't think there is one in that folder. Am I looking at the wrong thing?
To be clear, I'm trying to use the ngramSearch method.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... you have linked to a location on sourceforge which indeed contains language model files. If you look in the folder "US English" for example you will see a number of files with format *.lm.gz - grab one of those and inspect the contents. They do appear to be language models which may fit your purposes.